# Sort a list alphabetically

Tags: apex, class, list, getpicklistvalues

i have a multiselect picklist field **Roles** and i was trying to get the values in alphabetical order based on that(Roles) field.The method is as follows

```
public static List<opportunityRoles> getOppRoles(String oppId){
        Opportunity oppObj = [select id, Roles__c from Opportunity where id = : OppId limit 1];
        List<OpportunityRoles> oppRoleList = new List<OpportunityRoles>() ;
            if(oppObj != null && oppObj.Roles__c != null){
                for(String eachValue : oppObj.Roles__c.split(';')){                 
                        OpportunityRoles oppRL = new OpportunityRoles();
                        eachValue = eachValue.trim(); 
                        oppRL.rlName = eachValue;  
                        oppRoleList.add(oppRL);                                                
                }
                oppRoleList.sort();
            } 
            else{
                return null;
            }
        return oppRoleList;
    }
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. so, what is the issue? what do you observe? what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this:

```apex
public static List<opportunityRoles> getOppRoles(String oppId) {
    List<Opportunity> oppObj = [SELECT Roles__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: OppId];
    List<OpportunityRoles> oppRoleList = new List<OpportunityRoles>() ;
    if(oppObj.size() > 0 && oppObj[0].Roles__c != null) {
        String[] roles = oppObj[0].Roles__c.split(';');
        roles.sort();
        for(String eachValue : roles) {
            OpportunityRoles oppRL = new OpportunityRoles();
            oppRL.rlName = eachValue;
            oppRoleList.add(oppRL);
        } 
    }

    return oppRoleList;
}
```

Why have I done things differently?

It's much simpler to sort Strings than class objects. Therefore the above sorts Strings.

No Salesforce query with a WHERE on Id can result in more than one result. A LIMIT is unnecessary.

On the other hand the result of a Salesforce query is never null; the minimum is a list of 0 elements.

The `Id` in `SELECT Id` is (if you're not in the Developer Console) superfluous. Salesforce always queries Id's already implicitly.

Trimming values of picklist fields is unnecessary. You can't save picklist values with whitespace around them. Removing semicolons, no whitespace is left around them.

Finally, methods that return empty lists cause usually less trouble than methods that return null. Therefore I made the method return a list even in case no elements were selected. (But you might have special reasons, why you need null in this case.)

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph -- so many devs use nulls when empty collections is better

Comment: @cropredy :-) Just wondering, if "special reasons" exist at all, sometimes - I can't think of any!

Comment: as others on this site would say - collections with value = null is a "code smell"